# Is it possible to send keystroke and mouse move to flash objects from javascript?

Tags: flash

Is it possible to send keystroke and mouse move to flash objects from javascript for testing purpose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api) docs (especially getObjectById and embedSWF) and [flash.external.ExternalInterface](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#includeExamplesSummary)

In ActionScript,

```
package
{
    import flash.external.*

    public class MySprite extends Sprite {
    function MySprite():void 
    {
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("handleEventInAS", handleEventInAS);
    }

    function handleEventInAS(e:Object) 
    { 
       trace("in handleEventInAS with e="+e);
    }
}
```

Then in HTML/JS,

```
 <script src="swfobject.js"></script>
 <script>

     swfobject.embedSWF("myflash.swf","myflashid","100","100",9);
     var flashobj = swfobject.getObjectById("myflashid");
     window.onmousemove = connectjs2as;

     function connectjs2as(e)
     {
        if(flashobj)
            flashobj.handleEventInAS(e);
     }
 </script>
```

Note:  Requires FlashPlayer 9, which is why I added '9' in the embedSWF() call.

Comment: Thanks though I wanted to know if it is possible without having source code of flash :)

Comment: For that, you'd need 2 things. 1) swf served from the same host because of cross-domain policy issues, 2) the swf would have to have  ExternalInterface.addCallback calls made and you'd need to know what the swf used to name the callback (the first arg of addCallback).  For the second part, in may be possible to decompile the swf to get at what callbacks were added by ExternalInterface, though I have not attempted this before so not sure.